# No such file or directory : fastparquet.llibs\\.load_order

Tags: pyinstaller, dask, dask-dataframe, fastparquet

I am trying to convert a **CSV** file into **Parquet** format using **DASK**.

The code I'm using is :

```
 import dask.dataframe as dd
 name_function = lambda x: f"tablename.parquet"
 df = dd.read_csv('tablename.csv')
 df.to_parquet('Data\\', name_function=name_function, write_metadata_file=False, \
 engine='fastparquet')
```

It runs fine on my Pycharm editor.

But when I try to package the Python code into an .exe file using the command :

```
pyinstaller --add-binary "...\site-packages\teradatasql\teradatasql.dll;
teradatasql" code.py -F --onefile
```

I get the error :

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '...\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI25322\\
          fastparquet.libs\\.load_order'
```

How to fix this?

Comment: You need to escape the ```\``` in your ```df.to_parquet('Data\'....```.   Change it to ```Data\\'```

Comment: fastparquet maintainer here - I'm afraid I have absolutely no idea how pyinstaller works :|